# This function has a return type of but doesn't end with a return statement

Tags: flutter, dart

I have warning: "This function has a return type of 'FutureOr<List>', but doesn't end with a return statement."

My code

```
  Future<List<Task>> getAllTasks() async {
    _readTaskList().then((dynamic value) {
      if (value != null) {
        final List<Task> tasks = <Task>[];
        final List<Task> _tasks = value as List<Task>;
        tasks.forEach((dynamic element) {
          _tasks.add(_convertFromJsonToTask(element as Map<String, dynamic>));
        });
        return tasks;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't post the full code snippet of your function. Update your question with the full snippet.

Comment: The code you posted is not complete, post the complete code of your function

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code

Comment: From the code that you provided i think you should add a return after the _readTaskList() method like empty List [] or returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do this instead:

```
Future<List<Task>> getAllTasks() async {
  final dynamic value = await _readTaskList();
  
  if (value != null) {
    final List<Task> tasks = <Task>[];
    final List<Task> _tasks = value as List<Task>;
    tasks.forEach((dynamic element) {
      _tasks.add(_convertFromJsonToTask(element as Map<String, dynamic>));
    });
    return tasks;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Or if you really want to use `then`:

```
Future<List<Task>> getAllTasks() {
  return _readTaskList().then((dynamic value) {
    if (value != null) {
      final List<Task> tasks = <Task>[];
      final List<Task> _tasks = value as List<Task>;
      tasks.forEach((dynamic element) {
        _tasks.add(_convertFromJsonToTask(element as Map<String, dynamic>));
      });
      return tasks;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the value from `_readTaskList()` does not get returned before the `getAllTasks()` function is completely executed. Simply replacing `.then` with `await` will fix this problem

```dart
Future<List<Task>> getAllTasks() async {
    var value = await _readTaskList();
    if (value != null) {
      final List<Task> tasks = <Task>[];
      final List<Task> _tasks = value as List<Task>;
      tasks.forEach((dynamic element) {
        _tasks.add(_convertFromJsonToTask(element as Map<String, dynamic>));
      });
      return tasks;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```